# HOW can morality be a part of karma when societal rules change from culture to culture?

Tags: karma, dharma

Within sanatan dharma we consider karma to be universal ... but there are differences in the social rules between differing cultures on our planet. So how can this description of karma be accurate? I mean, it can hardly be universal if something is considered immoral in one city and perfectly acceptable in another.

Comment: @the destroyer: The question itself is hardly asking from the hinduism perspective, after all, he is is referring to other cultures...

Comment: @srimannarayana k v: 'To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post'; I am the author of the answer, so I don't see how I can critique it myself; if you are suggesting that this ought to be a comment - then say so; if you want me to add sources to this - well, its such a basic point I don't see the need for this; but I'll look for some.

Comment: @MoziburUllah See [Guidelines for new users answering questions](http://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125).

Comment: @sv: Thanks, I've been on the site long enough to know what guidelines are; I just found the moderators rude in the way they gave no time to correct the post before deleting it.

Comment: @MoziburUllah To be fair, your answer looked like a personal opinion and had no citations. The "cite sources" rule is taken pretty seriously around here. You can always edit and flag the mods to undelete it.

Comment: @s.v.: Ok, thanks for the advice; I'll take it into account next time I post.